# Microsoft Bot Builder activity.text POST to webhook with REST as JSON payload

Tags: c#, json, rest, bots, botframework

I want to create a bot using the Microsoft Bot Builder that will send received messages to a webhook endpoint. I've tried combining some examples found from searching around, but to no avail. I need some help to send the user input text to a webhook as a json payload with the value of text, here is the code i have now:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Bot_Application1.Dialogs
{

    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {

        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            // calculate something for us to return
            int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

            // return our reply to the user
            await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");

            // 
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://outlook.office.com/webhook/.../IncomingWebhook/.../...");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    text = "\"" + activity.Text + "\""
                    });
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            //

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

This is based off of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart

When I test this while monitoring with Fiddler I can see communication between the bot and the client, but never any REST http request. I'm not sure this is the best approach anyhow and would love some feedback.

A successful POST to this endpoint looks like this:

```
POST /webhook/.../IncomingWebhook/.../... HTTP/1.1
Host: outlook.office.com
User-Agent: insomnia/5.12.4
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 26
{
    "text":"Hello world!"
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You are forming the request, but not making the request at the end. The code is missing `(HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();`. Look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not making the request actually at the end. Change the code to :

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // calculate something for us to return
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        // return our reply to the user
        await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");

        // 
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://outlook.office.com/webhook/.../IncomingWebhook/.../...");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                text = "\"" + activity.Text + "\""
            });
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        //Make the actual request
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            //Get the output
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```